# JavaFX self contained application - Preferences API not working

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2

I've created a JavaFX application and deployed it as a self-contained app. The problem is that it is not being abble to write any file and not able to use the Preferences API.

The self-cointained is being generated by NetBeans with the following:

```
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
    <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}"
               nativeBundles="all"
               outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
        <fx:application name="${application.title}"
                        mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>
        <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
    </fx:deploy>
</target>
```

I've already read that it is necessary to sign my application in order to make it work.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: You'll have to request elevated permissions using `<fx:permissions elevated="true"/>`as  detailed here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference002.htm#CIABGCEE . This will, as you already figured, require you to sign the jar file. Are you generally familiar with digital signatures?

Comment: I don't think sarcan's comment is correct and I don't believe that signing the application is necessary.  The documentation on elevated permissions states: "This option has no impact on standalone applications, including self-contained applications."

Comment: <fx:permissions elevated="true"/> dose not work as jewelsea said. Anyway, thanks for your contribution. I don't believe it is necessary to sign, despite what I've read. Any other suggestion?

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting then? What OS are you testing on?

Comment: I am testing on Win7. No error is thrown. Is there any other way of seeing the error? When I execute the JAR it works, but when I run form the .exe created, it does not even with "Run As...".

Comment: Well, you said that you're not able to write files or access the preferences. What happens if you try to do so? Is some kind of exception being thrown, does the application freeze up?

Comment: In both scenarios, no exception is thrown, no freezing, nothins. Using preferences, it just create the nodes, but does not create the registry entries. As I said, only works when running the JAR. The executable bundle does not work.

Comment: I too would like to see an answer to this question. I also have need to run an application .exe in an elevated state.